# Use variable labels in putdocx text

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a word document with a number of histograms. I would like to describe each histogram with text using the variable label. I know that putdocx allows you to use functions and expressions from the documentation. I looked at the documentation for functions and expressions. It only has a documentation about label values (13.11). But I also know that I can extract the variable label using the local approach. So, I am wondering if it is possible to use variable label in putdocx text.

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/nlsw88.dta
histogram age
graph export "path/histogram.age.png", replace as(png)

** Using local to store the variable label
local age_lab: variable label age
di "`age_lab'"

putdocx begin
putdocx paragraph, style(Heading1)
putdocx text ("Histogram of `age_lab'")
putdocx image ("histogram.age.png")
putdocx save histogramreport, replace
```

Crossposted on [Stata Forum](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1699957-use-variable-labels-in-putdocx-text).

Comment: Answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1699957-use-variable-labels-in-putdocx-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [Stata Form](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1699957-use-variable-labels-in-putdocx-text):

Use `: var lab age` instead of `= age_lab` in putdocx.

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/nlsw88.dta
histogram age
graph export "path/histogram.age.png", replace as(png)

putdocx begin
putdocx paragraph, style(Heading1)
putdocx text ("Histogram of `: var lab age'")
putdocx image ("histogram.age.png")
putdocx save histogramreport, replace
```